# Activate small php condition at footer over page template

Tags: functions, page-template, footer

I wanted to run a basic php condition to my footer if correctly activated at certain page.

Code is:

```
if ( $photoSwipe == 1 ) {
  get_template_part( _ps );
}
```

So, if i am going to activate this plugin, i can trigger the `$photoSwipe = 1` to my certain page that will enable the `get_template_part(_ps)` to my footer area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a viable way to do it from a plugin, however it seems like it would make more sense in a template file.

If it's a universal option, you would create an option either through a custom settings page or just by initializing on plugin activation in the activation hook (if its a static value):

```
function wpse_photoswipe_activate_plugin() {
    $page_id = 123; // This could be an ID, or if you wanted, a template name
    add_option( 'wpse_activate_photoswipe', $page_id );
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse_photoswipe_activate_plugin' );

function wpse_photoswipe_deactivate_plugin() {
    delete_option( 'wpse_activate_photoswipe' );
}
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse_photoswipe_deactivate_plugin' );
```

Then in your footer template, you could use something like:

```
global $post;
if ( get_option( 'wpse_activate_photoswipe' ) === $post->ID ) {
    get_template_part( _ps );
}
```

However, if you want my opinion on the easiest way to do this, since it sounds like you're already editing template files, is to just update your existing code to:

```
if ( is_page( $page_id ) ) {
    get_template_part( _ps );
}
```

There are even more ways to do what you're suggesting but given the information you provided (existing theme hooks or `wp_footer`, for example), this should steer you in the right direction.

Comment: this code, solved my case... and you are correct, each template files are representing the PhotoSwipe template and others are not... Cause, I don't want to make the PhotoSwipe template visible on every page if it is not in use. Question on the `$page_id`, can i use array here?

Comment: @iMarkDesigns sure can. `is_page()` will take "Page ID, title, slug, or array of such" https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/